# How to post every object using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mern

As my "finalArr" has many items, how can I post every item using map. Below code works fine if I have only one item. But I'm facing problem when "finalArr" have more items in it.

```js
const orders = [{
  name: finalArr[0][0].name,
  productImage: finalArr[0][0].productImage,
  price: finalArr[0][0].price,
  quantity: finalArr[0][1],
}, ];

const customerData = {
  username,
  orders,
};

axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/api/cart", customerData)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map`. Try below:

```js
const orders = finalArr.map(e => ({
  name: e[0].name,
  productImage: e[0].productImage,
  price: e[0].price,
  quantity: e[1],  
}));
```